# Send data from robot to PC for Visualization

Tags: ros, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a mobile robot that maps the environment.

My problem is that I don't know how to see what my robot provides (map) when I unplug it from my PC.

I am using a raspberry pi (having ROS Noetic on Ubuntu Mate) in which I loaded all the files for automated obstacle avoidance.

How can I send the data from the robot to my PC so I can use gmapping and RViz to visualize the map remotely (no cables)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406424/send-data-from-robot-to-pc-for-visualization/) by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2022-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-14**:\

1. Write a publisher who can send the data from the robot.
2. Write a subscriber on your PC which can receive the transmitted data.
3. Use RViz to visualize it.

If you are unsure about implementing the above points, please feel free to look at [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

**Comment by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on 2022-09-16**:
That sounds really simple  , but what happens when both robot and pc running on different ROS masters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,
Try to follow the following steps :

1. First thing you’ll need is a wireless connection between your robot and your pc. You can connect both to the same wifi network and that should do it. Also both of them should have a static ip address.
2. You’ll need to write these lines in your robot’s `~/.bashrc` file. These lines will expose your ros master to the network and you can access this ros masters data from some other machine on the network.(robot ip should be replaced with actual robot ip and pc_ip with actual pc ip)

> `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://robot_ip:11311`  
> `export ROS_IP=robot_ip export`
> `ROS_HOSTNAME=robot_ip`
> Then you’ll need to write these lines in your pc’s ~/.bashrc file
> `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://robot_ip:11311`
> `export ROS_IP=pc_ip`
> `export ROS_HOSTNAME=pc_ip`

Now you source your `~/.bashrc` in robot and start your code from that terminal.Source `~/.bashrc` from your pc and try rostopic echo. If everything is done correctly you should be able to see all the topics. And now you can use them how ever you want.

---

Originally posted by [tomarRobin](https://answers.ros.org/users/42759/tomarrobin/) with karma: 111 on 2022-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on 2022-09-16**:
So this works . I do see the topics and nodes that are published from my robot but when i open rviz  there are no published data from /scan topic (while i can see it with rostopic list ).

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-16**:\

> but when i open rviz there are no published data from /scan topic

@Kostas Tziab: Some people have reported configuring the `/etc/hosts` file helped in this condition. However, please note that the `/etc/hosts` file should be configured on both computers.